# iPython: placing Python output into awk commands

Tags: shell, awk, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I'm getting the below behaviour in iPython, when I try to use Python's variables within shell commands.

Everything works fine with most of the shell commands (e.g. `cat`, `head`, etc.). Although, I'm not able to make it work with `awk`:

```
$ ipython
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.13.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: path = '/home/mux/'

In [2]: file = 'test.txt'

In [3]: !echo {path+file}
/home/mux/test.txt

In [4]: !cat {path+file}
Testing shell commands in iPython

In [5]: !awk '{print $1}' {path+file}
awk: fatal: cannot open file `{path+file}' for reading (No such file or directory)

In [6]: full_path = {path+file}

In [7]: full_path
Out[7]: {'/home/mux/test.txt'}

In [8]: !awk '{print $1}' full_path
awk: fatal: cannot open file `full_path' for reading (No such file or directory)

In [9]: !awk '{print $1}' /home/mux/test.txt
Testing
```

Can anyone explain the different behaviour between `awk` and the rest of shell commands?

Is there any workaround to make this work?

Comment: Yet `!awk '1' {file}` works.

Comment: Where is your awk program?

Comment: @PierreFrançois `1` is the simplest `awk` program already. `awk`'s default action is to print the input line if the program results in `True` and `1` is true so it prints every line. `7` works too! Try it `awk '1' /etc/hosts`

Comment: I know that. So, the problem is not awk but the invocation of awk by Python.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is using characters such as `{`, `}` and `$` which have a special meaning in shell commands inlined in iPython code. Depending on their intended use (evaluating a python variable or used for the shell command), you need to escape them by doubling them.

You want:

```
$ ipython3
Python 3.8.6 (default, Sep 25 2020, 09:36:53) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.19.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: path = "/tmp/"

In [2]: file = "test.txt"

In [3]: !echo {path+file}
/tmp/test.txt

In [4]: !cat {path+file}
hello

In [5]: !awk '{{print $$1}}' {path+file}
hello
```

It gets even worse when you have a complex command with pipes and an `awk` call late in the pipeline, because the behaviour of preceding commands changes.

```
In [6]: !echo {path+file} | awk '{print $1}'
{path+file}

In [7]: !echo {path+file} | awk '{{print $$1}}'
/tmp/test.txt
```

A last word, when you write `full_path = {path+file}`, you are creating a python set that contains the concatenation of strings.